# Audio introduce clicking disturbing noise after few minutes of live RTSP/RTP streaming

Tags: audio, directshow, rtsp, live-streaming

I'm using Directshow filters and getting clicking sound after few minutes of streaming. It's like a mouse clicking sound. If I do not use Reference clock, the issue resolve but the Audio-Video sync does not work and Lypsing doesn't work properly

While using VLC Player it works fine.

---

**Update:**

Thanks for your quick reply. I changed implementation of source filter, but still no success.

Previously the graph prepared as below:

Push Source -> ACM Wrapper -> DC-DSP Filter (Amplify filter) -> Render

I checked using graph edit, that DC-DSP filter can implement before decoder so implement change as below:

Push Source -> DC-DSP Filter (Amplify filter) -> ACM Wrapper -> Render

I checked timestamps of audio and video is working and lipsync is ok.

Is there any way to change the priority of audio in Directshow filter. In case of any delay in audio Directshow should not drop audio? In my case I think filter dropping audio not video, This may help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is achieved by proper time stamping of payload data. There is no RTSP streaming in stock filters, so you are using some third party filter, which is presumably having the time stamping issue.

To add to this, there is a ["rate matching"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390645) issue in case of mismatching rates of data origin and the clock of your audio renderer. There is an attempt to compensate it, but once again it is important how exactly the source filter is implementing it.

Comment: If it is dropping due to late delivery, Then issue should reproduce in VLS also but it works fine VLC player.

Comment: Late delivery means you can track it in your source code and do something appropriate and/or you time stamp it incorrectly. Note that actual playback takes place with respect to timings you attach to the data.

Comment: If VLS playing properly, then is it issue of time-stamp ? I'm using FFDSHow Video Decoder and for Audio using ACM Wrapper. Is there any settings. I'm new in live streaming so not a deep knowledge in AV Sync how it works etc.

Comment: VLC's proper playback says the stream is valid. Your playback glitches suggest you have some issues in code, most likely time stamping but not necessarily. It might be data loss or something. I'd bet on time stamps because clock-free run is fine.

Comment: I checked time-stamp nothing found, I'm using Live 555 for RTSP streaming